# Как заменить все символы в файле на другие

Tags: c++

Имеется квест, нужно заменить все символы "!" и "?" на точки"."
А остальное оставить на месте
Сейчас проходим потоки fstream
Но никак не могу понять как правильно сделать. 
Пробовал так
Объявлял поток fstream связывал с файлом и с помощью while и if пытался сделать задумку, идея такая была, если текущий символ, который лежит в потоке, fs, где fs- `fstream fs(path, fstream::in | fstream::out)`
То делал так

```
While (fs>>sym)
{
If (sym == '?' || sym =='!')
{
Sym='.';
Fs<<sym;
}
Else
Fs<<sym;
}
```

Мне подсказали, что когда я нахожу нужный мне символ под замену, то я должен с помощью seekg вернуться на символ назад и уже тогда менять мой `sym`
Но тут явно не только в этом дело и ещё есть ошибка. Буду рад помощи, спасибо

Comment: а с чего вы решили, что "тут явно не только в этом дело и ещё есть ошибка" - вы хоть попробовали? Вам уже подсказали решение и решиние правильное (хотя лучше бы сдесь обойтись без `fstream`), что вы еще хотите узнать?

Comment: почему у вас в коде, несмотря на тег, не c++? Напишите реальную программку и компилятор вам сам ответит на многие вопросы, не надо будет людей мучить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

string check(string a){
    for(int i=0;i<a.size();i++){
        if(a[i]=='?'||a[i]=='!')
            a[i]='.';
    }
    return a;
    return check(a);
}

int main(){
    ifstream read("read.txt");
    ofstream write("output.txt");
    string arr[100];
    string output[100];
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        read >> arr[i];
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        output[i]=check(arr[i]);
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        write << output[i];
}
```

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, в чем смысл `return check(a)` в функции `check`, он же никогда не выполниться

Comment: Без return check(a) рекурсив не будет работать!

Comment: какой **рекурсив**? открою секрет но он и тут не будет выполняться

Comment: Без этого код не заработает и учить меня не надо! Тогда мне придётся void использовать

Answer (score 0):

```
char sym;
while (fs >> sym && sym != '?' && sym != '!');
```

теперь ваш символ содержит последный прочитаемый символ, так что, если не достигли конца файла, то устанавливаем позицию для записи и потом записываем:

```
fs.seekp(-1, fs.cur);
fs << '.';
```

Если желаете выполнить дальше, то теперь установите новую позицию для чтения. Например на начало:

```
 fs.seekg(0, fs.beg);
```